# Function arithmetic library for python

Tags: python, function

I'm searching for a library that will let me manipulate functions with the standard operators (*, -, *, /, etc.).

Lets suppose you have a function `f(x) = x ** 2` and `g(x) = x + 2`. I'd like to be able to write `f * g` and get a new functor that is essentialy `x ** 2 * (x + 2)` or `f(g)` and get `(x + 2) ** 2`.

I know this is not too hard to implement, you'll just have to make a `Functor` class and overload it's `__call__` function, but I'm hoping there is a 3rd party library for it.

I'm not trying to use this for anything heavyweight just for learning. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sympy](http://sympy.org/) should do what you want.

Comment: Oooh, this is awesome! It even has a Dirac-delta function and can actually calculate convolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you're after, but does the `operator` module (in the standard library) help at all? It defines functions for all the standard arithmetic operators.

Comment: A computer algebra system, like what you'd use on a TI-83

Comment: I know that and for my dinky little sollution I used it, but you still cant multiply two functions to create a third.